# Function is not working as it should

Tags: image, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

```
def findClosestColor(newColor, colorList):

    """Takes in a Color object and a list of Color objects, and it finds
    which color in the list is most similar to newColor. It returns the
    most similar color from the list."""

    currClosest = colorList[0]
    currDist = distance(newColor, currClosest)
    for col in colorList:
        nextDist = distance(newColor, col)
        if nextDist > currDist:
            currClosest = col
            currDist = nextDist
    return currClosest


colors1 = [red, green, blue, yellow, pink, white, black]
c1 = findClosestColor(makeColor(240, 15, 30), colors1)

print(c1)
```

I'm getting

> (r=0, g=255, b=0) instead of (r=255, g=0, b=0).

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
if nextDist > currDist:
```

you have to flip it to less than:

```
if nextDist < currDist:
```